# Is Past Perfect or Simple past is optional in Reporting speech.?

Tags: past-perfect, reported-speech

In below linked NEWS i can see the Use of past perfect tense, Had alleged, in most of the sentences. It is very difficult to understand if it is really require there. it does not indicates two actions to differentiate it from simple past. by Using simple past it would give the same meaning. Then why past perfect is used?

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/shimla/baddi-murder-cong-bjp-resort-to-blame-game/articleshow/64086578.cms

Comment: I think it should be simple past. X was murdered on Sunday, and on Monday, Y alleged that blah blah blah.

Comment: It's probably just the style of that paper. An American newspaper editor would take a vicious hatchet to nearly all the uses of the past perfect in the article, and change them to simple past.